# PHP Regular Expression to remove all characters other than digits and periods

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` to remove all characters from a string except for numeric and period characters.

I can remove everything but numbers, however how can I make an exception for the '.' period character.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
$clean = preg_replace('/[^\\d.]+/', '', $str);
```

But you could also use `[^0-9.]` if you’re more familiar with that. Note that the `.` doesn’t need to be escaped inside the character class declaration as it’s not a special character inside there (only `]`, `\` and depending on the context also `^` and `-`).

Comment: @Tomalak: There is no *g* modifier in PHP’s PCRE. Replacing is always global.

Answer (score 9):

Remove everything that matches

```
[^0-9.]
```

e.g.

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $input);
```